# Apache Maven 3.5.3 installation issues on Windows 8.1

Tags: java, maven

I've downloaded Apache Maven 3.5.3 on Windows 8.1 and also set my environment variables as:

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10
M2_HOME = C:\Users\Shrads\Softwares\apache-maven-3.5.3\apache-maven\src
MAVEN_HOME = C:\Users\Shrads\Softwares\apache-maven-3.5.3\apache-maven\src
PATH = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10\bin;C:\Users\Shrads\Softwares\apache-maven-3.5.3\apache-maven\src\bin
```

But when I try to run "mvn -version" on my cmd, it shows an error:

```
Error: -classpath requires class path specification
```

Can someone help me with this issue?

Also, is it necessary to create a .m2 folder and settings.xml?

Comment: Don't set M2_HOME. It is not necessary.

Comment: It is. Some applications still access maven using M2
_HOME.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was my bad, I downloaded the src version instead of the bin version of the zip file.